# How to prevent Rxjava Subject on "onComplete"?

Tags: rx-java2

I need a RxJava subject that ignore `onComplete()`, So even I used [RxRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay), it call onComplete yet :(

```
private val mDisposables = CompositeDisposable()
private val mRelay: BehaviorRelay<Boolean> = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(true)
....
mDisposables += mRelay
        .observeOn(io)
        .throttleLatest(5, SECONDS)
        .flatMap { ... }
        .zipWith(...)
        .switchMap {...}
        .subscribeOn(io)
        .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<UiData>() {
          override fun onComplete() {
            Timber.d("COMPLETED")
          }

          override fun onNext(it: UiData) {
            Timber.d(it.toString())
          }

          override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            Timber.e(e)
          }
        })
  }
```

Why always do `onComplete` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably your usage of `.zipWith` which limits the stream to the shortest participant, regardless of whether the other streams ever finish.

Comment: Thats impossible to say without knowing why you're using the `zipWith` and what you originally intended for it to do.But in general toggling through a relay requires that the actual stream be contained in a `switchMap` so changing the relay can disable the stream entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I realized `.zipWith()` breaks stream. Finally I replaced `.zipWith()` with `.flatMap()` .

Thanks @Kiskae